# Question mark in print_r array key

Tags: php

I have a small form for setting event reminders.  Couple check boxes and some date times.  Nothing fancy.  One field in particular is getting passed into php with something funky:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="smsGetReminder" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="smsGetUpdates" value="1" checked />
```

Pretty basic right?  2 check boxes checked by default.  Now when they get posted (send as $_GET) a question mark magically appears in front of smsGetUpdates so that it looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[?smsGetBlast] => 1 
[smsGetReminder] => 1 
[dp1] => 06/18/2011 
[rHrs] => 07 
[rMins] => 00 
[rAmpm] => PM 
[smsPhone] => 1234567890 
[getEmail] => 1 [f] => p 
)
```

Where is that question mark coming from?  When I extract $_GET everything works as expected except that one.  The validation portion tells me $smsGetBlast doesn't exist because obviously it has a question mark there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

~~~~SOLVED~~~~

I had accidentally put a ? in my ajax data string.  The jquery documentation led me to believe it was needed when it was not.

Comment: Could you add the html of the complete form?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `var_export` or `var_dump` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: Did you at some point copy and paste the `name` attribute values in your html code? Could be there is a hidden unicode character there or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably inadvertently inserted a "strange" character into the `name` attribute of the `smsGetBlast` input element <sub>(Which is missing in the question, nudge nudge)</sub>.

My crystal ball tells me that you inadvertently inserted fancy quotes instead of `"` after `name=` in that element.

Comment: i went ahead and redid the quotes, definitely standard quotes in there.